# How do you write "Speak friend and enter" in Elvish characters?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkien-languages

[image: door of durin]

I'm looking to get this as a tattoo, but unfortunately because of the size I am unable to fit all of the writing found at the top of the archway. I was looking to maybe just have the part that says, "Speak friend and enter" or "pedo mellon a minno". Which part of the script there are those words? I'm guess it's the top line on the left side of the archway that says it -- does that seem right?

[What language was the inscription on the Doors of Durin written in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92877/what-language-was-the-inscription-on-the-doors-of-durin-written-in/95261#95261)

Comment: See, now I'm seeing that star in the middle and thinking about your question, and there's a horrified part of me that wants to know where you plan to place this tattoo.

Comment: @Broklynite Best. Tattoo. Idea. Ever. (Just wish the Sindarin for ‘speak!’ weren’t _pedo_.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I had noted that but thought it might perhaps be in bad taste.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not very good at translating Tengwar personally, but every [online source](http://www.jrrvf.com/~glaemscrafu/english/portesmoria.html) I can find agrees that it's actually the right-hand side of the top line:

From a German fan named [Gernot Katzer](http://gernot-katzers-spice-pages.com/tolkien/tengwar.html?tengwar_s.html):
[image]

From [Reddit user Wiles_](https://www.reddit.com/r/tolkienfans/comments/33ljux/speak_friend_and_enter_elvish/):
[image]

And from a fan named [Dan Smith, courtesy of theonering.net](http://fan.theonering.net/~rolozo/tengwar/tengwar/exlotrm.htm)
[image]